# How to profile audio callback

Tags: c++, macos, audio, profiling, stack-trace

I'm writing a music player. I already have done a lot to improve the performance of my audio callback:

- All decoding etc. is of course done in a separate thread. That will fill up some buffers.
- To avoid any locking, I avoided any mutexes and coded all relevant structures just based on atomic operations. It's basically a lock-less FIFO.
- I try to avoid page faults by using `mlock` on all the allocated memory.
- I set my thread to realtime constraints via `thread_policy_set` (similar as [here](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/base/threading/platform_thread_mac.mm)).

It sometimes still happens that I get underflows. I wonder how to debug that because I want to know what causing them.

- I was thinking about maybe a way to trace the current execution of the audio callback if it took longer than 2ms or so. But how could I do that?
- Also, maybe it still reads some memory which results in page faults. How can I debug those?
- All the code in the callback is still somewhat complex. Maybe it's just too complicated. I could work around that by introducing another indirection and make the code really minimal by using just a simple ring buffer. That would introduce some more latency and I'm not sure if that is really the problem.

Comment: Have you looked at Instruments? Time Profiler & System Trace (shows thread scheduling) should give you some insight.

Comment: What is the buffersize/samplerate you're aiming for? i.e. how much time you have in total in the callback? Just asking cause we have software that does rec/process/play in <5mSec callbacks (and that includes reading from disk), did none of the optimizations you talk about and have no underruns.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman: I did that but it didn't helped so much because they show only the average numbers and they look fine. The underflow happens quite rarely. I need somehow to find a way to capture the trace only if it takes too long.

Comment: @stijn: It happens even at 48kHz but ideally I want it also to support 96kHz or 192kHz. I tried with several buffersizes but it didn't helped so much. But maybe that is also a problem with my intermediate layer PortAudio. I got the best results when I let the OS choose automatically the buffer size.

Comment: As a first step then try to determine if it is your code rather then any of the underlying layers causing the problem? Find out min/max amount of time your code spends in the callback. If it is never even close to the max possible amount, your code isn't the culprit.

Comment: You ought to wire the maximum stack you're likely to need and any program code that runs with real-time priority.  The latter is important as the kernel is at liberty to evict memory-mapped program text pages from physical pages any time it pleases.

Answer (score 0):

What I would try is, if I have a procedure that is supposed to complete in less than 2ms, I would set a 2ms alarm-clock interrupt when entering the procedure, and clear it when exiting the procedure.
Even if the overtime occurs rarely, this is sure to get it.

So when the interrupt occurs, I can catch it in the debugger and examine the stack.
Would this catch it in the act of doing what is taking extra time?
Maybe, maybe not, but doing it several times is bound to reveal something interesting.

The other thing I would do is simply look for speedups in the callback itself.
To do this, I would just randomly pause it manually a number of times while it's running, and each time examine the stack.
I would simply ignore any samples where the callback was not on the stack.
For the remaining samples, where the callback is on the stack, it will be at a random position in the state sequence of the callback, so chances are excellent that if there's anything it's doing whose optimization would save much time, I will see it doing it.

Comment: I think even syscalls in the callback are considered bad as they might block, but for debugging, this is probably ok. :)

Comment: @Albert: If there are blocking syscalls in the callback, then the pauses will find them, if they account for significant time. If they don't, then there's no need to worry about them. By the way, I forgot to mention the idea of just putting a long loop around the callback so your pauses are sure to land in it. Then after you've sped it up, remove the loop and it will fly.